# Kreyszig "Advanced Engineering Mathematics", Sixth Edition, Section 1.6, Question 35

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Been struggling with/trying to understand one part of this question. The subject is integrating factors in first order Differential Equations. This is not a homework question, it is for personal study. The question for reference is as follows:

*It is interesting to note that if $F(x, y)$ is an integrating factor, $1/F(x,y) = 0$ may sometimes yield an additional solution of the corresponding equation. To see this, consider*

$$xdy - ydx = 0;$$

*show that an integrating factor is $F = 1/x^2$ and leads to $y = cx$. Show that $1/F = x^2 = 0$ yields the additional solution $x = 0$ of the given equation which is not included in $y = cx$.*

NB: My problem with this question is the last sentence, solving the actual equation was straight forward. I"m having trouble solving the last sentence of this equation because it seems to me that $x = 0$ is an obvious solution by inspection of the original equation, but it also seems to me that the question is asking for more than that. Any pointers/directions/answers(!) would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the conjunctive.

It is always important to avoid division by zero, for instance by reducing the domain by the zero curve of the divisor. Sometimes such a reduction hides or loses a solution of the original problem, thus it is important to test this.

In the most simple case one can look at $y'=y$ solved via separation. One would have to divide by $y$, thus has to exclude $y=0$ from this path. Testing finds that $y\equiv 0$ is actually a solution. (Here it gets integrated into the general solution formula $y=Ce^x$, but that does not always happen.)